# Following the MVC paradigm straight, what is the correct way to do this?

Tags: php, templates

Let's suppose i have a method $users->vip_time(), which will return either an array with the remaining time, like {15, 8, 48}, or Null if the user have no vip.

It should be displayed to the user in a single place, either his vip time, or that he's not vip.

Should it go into the controller like that:

```
$vip_time = $user->vip_days();
$context['remaining_time'] = 'Free account';
if ($vip_time)
    $context['remaining_time'] = $vip_time[0] . ' days and ' . $vip_time[1] . ' hours.';
```

Or should it go into the view, like that:

```
//Controller
$context['remaining_time'] = $user->vip_days();

//View
<p><?=(!$remaining_time) ? 'Free account' : $remaining_time[0] . ' days and ' . $remaining_time[1] . ' hours.';?></p>
```

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: I fail to see anything even vaguely like MVC in this.

Comment: Design patterns aren't like cake recipes. Truth to be said: Initially, MVC wasn't concepted for web. So, you'll never follow it "straight" as you said... But just to say, your 2nd approach is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to go with your second approach. As a rule of thumb you can keep in mind: never process static text in your controllers. That stuff always belongs into views.

Answer (score -1):

Put it in the View, as it is something already on the page from load, not something retrieved with AJAX.

Comment: What does this have to do with AJAX?

Comment: Because then you put it in the controller which directs to a function that echoes out VIP which is the AJAX response

Comment: not really, JSON can encode null values just fine. You should never do value formatting inside the controller, that's the views job

Comment: It's not in the controller mate. I said that the model takes care of that, but only a controller can direct requests to a model, right?